# How to return new array or object containing values between two variables

Tags: reactjs

How do I get a new array, filtering values within two variables ? The data contains a date that is in epoch and I would like to return a range. The values I would like to pass as parameters are the From Date, To Date, the Array and the Header (date). The result should be an array that only contains the dates found between those two variables.

```
//the data : date is the one to filter from
[
    {
        "id": 2097190,
        "date": 1652965848416,
        "client": 49372,
        "level": 2,
        "source": 3,
        "status": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2097185,
        "date": 1652965848761,
        "client": 49372,
        "level": 2,
        "source": 3,
        "status": 0
    }, 
]
...
```

I tried to solve this with the following :

```
    const returnArray = (dateFrom, dateTo, myArray, headeritem) => {
    if (!dateFrom) {
    return myArray;
    } else {
    return myArray = myArray.filter((item) => {
        return Object.keys(item).some(key => item[headeritem] >= dateFrom & item[headeritem] <= dateTo);
    });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const returnArray = (dateFrom, dateTo, myArray, headeritem) => {
    if (dateFrom && dateTo) {
        myArray = myArray.filter(item => Object.keys(item).some(key => item[headeritem] >= dateFrom & item[headeritem] <= dateTo));
    }
    return myArray.map(item => item[headeritem]);
};
```